# Tercer subnivel del menú se pone bajo el segundo subnivel

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Descargué una plantilla con el menú ya hecho y simplemente le cambié los títulos y direcciones.

La plantilla es de dos niveles, mas requiero poner otro nivel. El tercer submenú  se amontona al subnivel 2 si lo pongo en las primeras partes del subnivel 2, como un fondo del subnivel 2. Quiero que salga a la derecha del submenú 2 y no abajo de él.

Creo que es algo del CSS y del acomodo de etiquetas, mas no sé qué ya cambiar, ya le hice varias pruebas y no cambia.

Imagen donde sale abajo y no a la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código de inicio:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Default Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  background: url('img/denim.png');
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.wrap {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 4em auto;
}

nav {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#fff), to(#ccc));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 8px 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ededed), to(#fff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #fff);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: #222;
}

/* Dropdown styles */

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Displays the dropdown on hover and moves back into position */
.menu li:hover ul {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Persistant Hover State */
.menu li:hover a {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ccc), to(#ededed));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc, #ededed);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: #222;
}

.menu li:hover ul a {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#eee), to(#fff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #fff);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PAGINA INICIO</title>
  <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="iconic.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="prefix-free.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index_admin2.php"><span class="iconic home"></span> Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic plus-alt"></span> Ventas</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Buscar Ventas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">En Proceso</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lista</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic chat"></span> Distribuidores</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nuevo Distribuidor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buscar Distribuidor</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic check"></span> Productos</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="producto_nuevo.php">Nuevo Producto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Luces</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Valeros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">etc...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic key"></span>Marcas</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MonkeyLight</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bkool</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Motorex</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mono</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Luces</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="consultar_usuarios.php"><span class="iconic chat-alt"></span> Usuarios</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="usuario_nuevo.php">Nuevo Usuario</a></li>
            <li><a href="consultar_usuarios.php">Consultar Usuarios</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic book"></span> Datos</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="crear_usuarios.php">Datos Personales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Configuracion</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Cupones</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><strong>BUSCADOR GRAL: </strong>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" size="60">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="BUSCAR">
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <center>
        <p><img src="Gráficas-en-Excel-16.png" width="596" height="331" alt="" /></p>
      </center>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: incluye las pruebas que hiciste y sus resultados

Comment: Hola, vi que tienes tags mal declaradas en tu HTML, eso puede generar resultados inesperados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema como dices es que los estilos del menú sólo contemplan la posibilidad de tener los subniveles uno debajo del otro y no al lado. Si quieres que se pongan a la derecha, puedes cambiar un poco los estilos para indicar que el primer nivel 2 irá abajo, y el 3 irá a la derecha.

Para eso puedes modificar las siguientes 4 reglas. El cambio puede parecer menor (apenas es añadir algunos `>`) pero afecta más de lo que parece porque estamos indicando que los estilos solo aplicarán a los hijos directos:

```
/* Displays the dropdown on hover and moves back into position */
.menu li:hover > ul {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Persistant Hover State */
.menu  li:hover > a {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ccc), to(#ededed));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc, #ededed);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: #222;
}

.menu  li:hover > ul > a {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu  li:hover > ul > li > a:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#eee), to(#fff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #fff);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Y añadir una más (para los submenús del tercer nivel en adelante, que se pongan a la derecha):

```
.menu > li > ul li:hover ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esos cambios, se ve algo mejor (aunque te quedaría estilizarlo un poco si quieres para mejorar algo las sombras, pero eso ya es otro tema diferente). He cambiado un poco el orden de los menús para que se vea que no sólo funciona estando el menú de tercer nivel en la última posición:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Default Styles 
--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  background: url('img/denim.png');
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.wrap {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 4em auto;
}

nav {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#fff), to(#ccc));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 8px 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ededed), to(#fff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #fff);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: #222;
}

/* Dropdown styles */

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Displays the dropdown on hover and moves back into position */
.menu li:hover > ul {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu > li > ul  li:hover  ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

/* Persistant Hover State */
.menu  li:hover > a {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#ccc), to(#ededed));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc, #ededed);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  color: #222;
}

.menu  li:hover > ul > a {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu  li:hover > ul > li > a:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#eee), to(#fff));
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ededed, #fff);
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PAGINA INICIO</title>
  <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="iconic.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="prefix-free.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index_admin2.php"><span class="iconic home"></span> Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic plus-alt"></span> Ventas</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Buscar Ventas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">En Proceso</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lista</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic chat"></span> Distribuidores</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nuevo Distribuidor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buscar Distribuidor</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic check"></span> Productos</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="producto_nuevo.php">Nuevo Producto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Luces</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Valeros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">etc...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic key"></span>Marcas</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MonkeyLight</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Motorex</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mono</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Luces</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bkool</a></li>
            

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="consultar_usuarios.php"><span class="iconic chat-alt"></span> Usuarios</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="usuario_nuevo.php">Nuevo Usuario</a></li>
            <li><a href="consultar_usuarios.php">Consultar Usuarios</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic book"></span> Datos</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="crear_usuarios.php">Datos Personales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Configuracion</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Cupones</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><strong>BUSCADOR GRAL: </strong>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" size="60">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="BUSCAR">
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <center>
        <p><img src="Gráficas-en-Excel-16.png" width="596" height="331" alt="" /></p>
      </center>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias, ya se soluciono.. gracias por la ayuda amigo, lo otro voy a buscar acomodorlo mejor